# How to enter business order

Tags: usability, website-design, forms, design-patterns, input

If i have input for order (**business sort**) for specific entity like this :

[image]

Where (`10,20,30,40,50`) are numbers entered from the user for the order of these contracts and this order is used in business .

---

My question is:

Right now i allow the user to enter the order through a text box.
From `UX` perspective what's the best way to enter business order ?

Comment: This question is pretty vague. Is there an issue you're experiencing by letting the customer enter in numbers through a text box?

Comment: @AlanGeorge : no i ask if there's a better way to enter numbers express about business order rather than a textbox ?

Comment: How many rows are typically displayed? That's an important consideration in coming up with a solution. A UI optimized for 5-20 lines may not work with 200.

Comment: @EricStoltz we talk about 5-20 per category

Answer (score 1):

Text boxes are typically the best entry method for numbers, as they are lightweight and work on every browser. However, you can take some steps to improve your text box:

**1. Validation**

To ensure the user doesn't enter in bad data (i.e. text, symbols), validate the text box to ensure it only contains numbers. This can be done in a number of ways, including Regex /^[0-9+]*$/, and [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp).

A typical validation UI might look like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJSfsl.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**2. Autocomplete**

If the business numbers are known on your end, a simple autocomplete form saves the user time. Just be careful to limit what numbers the user sees, i.e. only show them business numbers associated with their account.

For example:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOgy6k.png)</sup>

Comment: Note:Those numbers are the `order` of set of contracts

Comment: By order, do you mean sort? Or order as in purchase?

Comment: I mean `sort` (business sort)

Comment: I still don't understand. Are these numbers used as indexes for the contracts?

Comment: Those numbers are used to order(sort) the contracts for the next promotion (business issue)

Comment: Is there a specific reason they are multiples of ten?

Comment: No the user enters random numbers to sort

Comment: If they're just used to define the order that the lines will be "used", then you may want to consider "move up" and "move down" buttons: either on each line or (if appropriate) for the currently selected line. You could, in certain cases, even make the rows draggable.  You might also want to see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/546375/2096401)

Answer (score 0):

### Combo Box

A combo box is a commonly used graphical user interface widget (or control). Traditionally, it is a combination of a drop-down list or list box and a single-line editable textbox, allowing the user to either type a value directly or select a value from the list.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about only 5-20 items in the list, I would suggest that exact ordering may not be as important as establishing priority. For example, if there are 20 items, is item 13 absolutely more important than 14? Can I work on 14 if there's a blocker on 13? There's probably no great difference between 13 and 14.

Therefore, a more manageable solution may be to have three priority levels: high, medium and low. Let the user choose a priority from a dropdown or via radio buttons. Re-order the items on refresh or subsequent visits (or provide a refresh button if necessary to see the new order immediately).

Business may recoil from labeling anything a low priority; in that case adopt language that will be more internally palatable!